# Disabling CCButton in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, spritebuilder

I have a CCButton declared in `Status.m` - it is created via a code connection in SpriteBuilder:

```
@implementation Status
{
    CCButton *_button;
}
```

The method `block` is called when the button is pressed -- in this method I'd like to disable further interaction with the button.

```
- (void)block
  {
      // Disable user interaction
  }
```

I cannot find how to do disable this with in the built-in methods!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`CCControl.enabled`](http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/Classes/CCControl.html#//api/name/enabled) property should do it:

```
- (void)block
{
    _button.enabled = NO;
}
```